# Google Bigquery: Incompatible table partitioning specification

Tags: hadoop, google-api, google-bigquery

While submitting a copy job from a temporary table that isn't partitioned to the final  table that has partition by day, I recieve

```
cause:java.io.IOException: ErrorMessage: Incompatible table partitioning specification. Expects partitioning specification interval(type:day), but input partitioning specification is none;
```

So are there any limitations on the input table for copy job to partitioned table and  how can they be overcome? Temporary table is created inside hadoop bigquery-connector class using  Load job. And JobConfigurationLoad doesn't have specification of TimePartitioning at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try using the partition meta-table for the desired day for the time being? I have filed an issue internally to support this scenario. Something like the following should work:

```
bq --project_id=<project> cp <source_table> <destination_partitioned_table$20160809>
```

Comment: Hi, Pavan!
Thanks for your reply! The main question is - can I specify  non-existing partion? I mean if for example I specify destination_partitioned_table$20160801 and it has no data will it be automatically created?

Comment: Yes, it will automatically get created in this case.