# Google Bigquery: Spark - Incompatible table partitioning specification

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, hadoop2

While submitting a copy job from a temporary table that isn't partitioned to the final table that has partition by day, I recieve

> cause:java.io.IOException: ErrorMessage: Incompatible table
>   partitioning specification. Expects partitioning specification
>   interval(type:day), but input partitioning specification is none;

Seeing another person with this issue this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852715/google-bigquery-incompatible-table-partitioning-specification/41547131#41547131)

I am now facing the same issue, using the Spark `saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset` which using the connector creates temp table then presumably using the copy command to load the data to the destination

Is there an eta on the fix [Pavan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5071793/pavan-edara)?

Answer (score 1):

We have recently made a change to support this (it will copy into the partition for the current date in this case). We expect the change to be released soon.

Comment: Thanks [Paven](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5071793/pavan-edara) any idea when this will be released? where can I see it announced?