# Google Bigquery: Partitioning specification needed for copying date partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery

Note: this is nearly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852715/google-bigquery-incompatible-table-partitioning-specification) with the distinction that in this case, the source table is date partitioned and the destination table does not yet exist.  Also, the accepted solution to that question didn't work in this case.

I'm trying to copy a single day's worth of data from one date partitioned table into a new date partitoined table that I have not yet created.  My hope is that BigQuery would simply create the date-partitioned destination table for me like it usually does for the non-date-partitioned case.

Using BigQuery CLI, here's my command:

```
bq cp mydataset.sourcetable\$20161231 mydataset.desttable\$20161231
```

Here's the output of that command:

> BigQuery error in cp operation: Error processing job
>   'myproject:bqjob_bqjobid': Partitioning specification must be provided
>   in order to create partitioned table

I've tried doing something similar using the python SDK: running a select command on a date partitioned table (which selects data from only one date partition) and saving the results into a new destination table (which I hope would also be date partitioned).  The job fails with  the same error:

> {u'message': u'Partitioning specification must be provided in order to
>   create partitioned table', u'reason': u'invalid'}

Clearly I need to add a partitioning specification, but I couldn't find any documentation on how to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create the partitioned destination table first ([as per the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#copying_partitioned_tables)):

> If you want to copy a partitioned table into another partitioned
>   table, the partition specifications for the source and destination
>   tables must match.

So, just create the destination partitioned table before you start copying. If you can't be bothered specifying the schema, you can create the destination partitioned table like so:

```
bq mk --time_partitioning_type=DAY mydataset.temps
```

Then, use a query instead of a copy to write to the destination table. The schema will be copied with it:

```
bq query --allow_large_results --replace --destination_table 'mydataset.temps$20160101''SELECT * from `source`'
```

Comment: Too bad there's no option to just tell bigquery to add day partitioning to the destination table.  But it's great that I don't have to specify the schema--that's painful part.

Comment: Just wanted to know. Suppose I wanted to empty a column's value while copying it from source to destination (rest of the columns' values intact), how can I achieve that?

Comment: Just wanted to add in case any one else comes across this in 2021, it seems like it works now if you run the "bq mk" command followed by the original "bq cp", without writing the copy as a query.